# Insert Unicode character in Microsoft Office as Wine Application on PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office, unicode-entry

Occasionally, I want to insert unicode characters in Microsoft Office via PlayOnLinux as Wine application.

- With most gnome-applications I can press [CRTL-SHIFT-U and then the hex number of the unicode character](https://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux).
- On windows this is possible by holding ALT and using the numpad keys.

This both does not work in Office. Is there an easy way to insert unicode characters (mainly greek)?

Comment: try setting your keyboard to an "international" layout like the `us` layout variants `intl` or `altgr-intl` and/or setting a `Compose` key.  i've not tried with MS Office but most unicode-aware windows tools i've used via wine have accepted characters with both `AltGr` and `Compose` entry methods.  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key ... your default compose sequences can be found in `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert any symbol using the Symbol window. The button `Symbol` (to show the window) is in the `Insert` tab. This way works for Microsoft Word. If it's needed to add any symbol to another application - you can copy and paste symbols.

[image: Symbol window]

There is the `Character code` field where you can enter the symbol code what you want to insert.